# Alert causes scroll top

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, alert

I'm developing an asp application and I have a problem when my alerts are visualized. In particular I have a long page and when my alert is visualized the page scroll on the top, then when I click on OK the page return normal. I'm using [scrollsaver script](https://github.com/hasheminezhad/scrollsaver/blob/master/ScrollSaver/scrollsaver.js).
I'm trying also adding `return false` after the alert but it is not working.

I added this function in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

somefunction = function () { alert('foo'); return false; }

</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnCarousel" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnCarousel_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-orange  " Visible="false" ToolTip="Change to Carousel and Viceversa"  />
```

In cs page

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "somefunction", "somefunction();", true);
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The reason the page scrolls to the top is bacause a POSTBACK happens. The browser renders the page again, from scratch. Try using `OnClientClick="somefunction"` for the button

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I do this:

I create this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function alertMe(message) {
      setTimeout(function () { alert(message); }, 100);
   }
</script>
```

and in the cs page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alertMe('test');", true);
```

In this way I "avoid" the postback